# Weaviate - top hits for with_near_vector() doesn't include the record whose vector perfectly matches query vector

Tags: cosine-similarity, weaviate, approximate-nn-searching

I have a very large Weaviate vector storage class (700,000 records) in which I pass my own custom vectors. I’m trying to get distances against a vector I pass as below. The vector is actually a match to one of the records, so I know the top hit should be the record with the identical vector (distance very close to 0). However, when I ask for top hits, the “closest” record is returning a distance of around 0.10, and this record is definitely not the record that matches my query vector perfectly (node_type="type1" instead of "type2").

```
# NOTE: mean_emb is a numpy array that matches a record pushed to the MyClass weaviate class.
# This theoretically should return distances from all 700k records to specified vector, since "distance" = 1.0, but I get why it wouldn't computationally
result = (client.query.get("MyClass", ["message", "node_type", "my_id", "timestamp"])
          .with_near_vector({"vector": mean_emb.tolist(), "distance": 1.0})
          .with_additional(["vector", "distance"]).do())
result = result["data"]["Get"]["MyClass"]
print(len(result))  # only 11,100 distances are returned
```

It looks like `with_offset()` doesn’t like it when the offset is >100,000.

I have tried pagination using `with_after()` but with_after doesn’t support queries with `with_near_vector()`, and I have also tried `with_offset()` + `with_limit()`, but this is terribly slow. Is there a workaround / what am I doing wrong here / how to query my class so that my top N query includes the true record match (distance close to 0)?

To prove there is in fact a record with distance ~0.000. Here’s the query that highlights the records that matches the vector:

```
where_filter = {"path": ["node_type"], "operator": "Equal", "valueText": "type2"}
result = (client.query.get("MyClass", ["message", "node_type", "my_id", "timestamp"])
          .with_near_vector({"vector": mean_emb.tolist()})
          .with_additional(["distance", "id"]).with_where(where_filter).do())
print(result)
```

Gives me this (I’ve changed the values of some of the record meta-data to protect data):

```
{'data': {'Get': {'MyClass': [{'_additional': {'distance': -1.9073486e-06,
      'id': 'fdb00f95-2c07-462c-84cd-9380c6777801'},
     'my_id': 'Record that matches the vector passed',
     'message': None,
     'node_type': 'type2',
     'timestamp': None},
    {'_additional': {'distance': 0.6122676,
      'id': '0deb152a-eef0-485c-ad6e-c9e29f9a3915'},
     'my_id': 'Another type2 record that doesn't match vector passed',
     'message': None,
     'node_type': 'type2',
     'timestamp': None}]}}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insist on having the the exact match appear at the top, then, you need to tweak the indexing algorithm (HNSW) to increase recall. Try [increasing the value of the ef paramater](https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/configuration/indexes#how-to-configure-hnsw).

Comment: I haven't yet been able to verify that this solves my problem, but you've definitely unlocked a part of the documentation I didn't know to look at, so thank you so much! I tried ef = 100 but top hits still were not there. I noticed that the doc of interest had two properties that were being vectorized, whereas docs of type 1 only had one property that was vectorized. Would that affect the rankings? I'll have to repush and test but it'll take a few days to verify, etc.

Comment: ef=100 is too small in opinion, considering the number of records you have. Have a look here to understand what ef controls: 

https://github.com/nmslib/hnswlib/blob/master/ALGO_PARAMS.md

Comment: Great references / links! Thank you for highlighting this functionality for me!